# Primefaces in mobile application

Tags: primefaces, mobile-application

We have developed an application using JSF2 and Primefaces. Application is a very small scale web application which has Datatable(with search,filter and pagination ) and file upload and download features. Customer wants it to convert to an mobile application.
What are the possibilities and how i can proceed in this.
Need some suggestion on the implementation of the same.

Comment: Anybody worked on  Primefaces Mobile or (PFM)?

Comment: Did you try just running it on a mobile device? And must ut be an 'app' or can it still be a webapp?

Comment: Yes. We tried on mobile device and ui is distorted. Webapp compatible with mobile devie would be fine.

Comment: Then look into the custom css you use. Most PF components in 5.2 and up work reasonably well if you use the plain non-mobile versions.